# How to get CLLocationManager result before all viewDidLoad stuff loads?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, cllocationmanager

Please check the code:

```
 let manager = CLLocationManager()

//Location manager to determine the current location
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let location = locations[0]
    lat = location.coordinate.latitude
    lon = location.coordinate.longitude
    let currentLocation = CLLocation(latitude: lat!, longitude: lon!)
}
```

And i have few more functions in viewDidLoad():

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    manager.delegate = self
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    //Here i want to get the result immediately, but...
    manager.startUpdatingLocation()

   parseJSONfunction()
   anotherFunction()
   anotherFunction2()
   ...}
```

So, i can't get the result of `manager.startUpdatingLocation()` function until all `viewDidLoad()` stuff loads. 
The question: Is it possible to get coordinates before all other functions runs? If yes, please describe how?

Comment: You can define a singleton class with all your LocationManager logic and initialize that class in your appDelegate

Comment: @ReinierMelian Sure, doing that might improve things. But can we really be sure that we gonna get our location *before* the first view controller is presented? In the general case, I don’t think so...

Comment: Nope. In general, you need to move those other functions into your `locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations)` method. A thought, though: can you start with a default location of some sort (or maybe the user's last location)? If so, you can store that in the `UserDefaults` and pull it out in `viewDidLoad` for the functions to use initially. Then, when the actual location info comes back, you can respond appropriately with the new data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The question: Is it possible to get coordinates before all other functions runs?

In a word, no. The location manager is asynchronous. You ask it to start updating your location and it fires up the GPS and tries to get a fix (it also uses cell towers, WiFi base stations, etc.) It can take several seconds (or longer) in order to get a reasonably accurate reading.

When I'm writing location-aware apps, I usually start the location manager, and in my `locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations:)` method I check the horizontal accuracy of the result and only take it if it's at least reasonably accurate. This can make it take even longer.

If you load a viewController it's synchronous. The system does the setup, which causes various framework calls to fire, and then viewDidLoad gets called, **synchronously** once the view loads. If you start the location manager when the user asks to display a new view controller, you can't possibly have a location fix by the time viewDidLoad is called.

If you load your app, have the app delegate invoke a singleton to begin location updates, and then wait for the user to switch to your other screen, where you then ask the singleton for the location during viewDidLoad you have a good chance of getting a good location reading, but even then it isn't certain.